# Do I need to instantiate this class (SimpleRoleProvider)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am creating a role in Simplemembership like so:

```
Roles.CreateRole("Admin")
```

It works fine, however I have seen people instantiate and then call the CreateRole method like so:

```
var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider;

roles.CreateRole("Admin")
```

So this is effectively like saying:

```
Roles.Provider.CreateRole("Admin")
```

My question is, is the way I am doing it OK as I am using the system.web.security.roles class without instantiating it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not instantiation. It's just a cast to local variable:

```
var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)System.Web.Security.Roles.Provider;
```

There is no any difference between these two approaches. They are the same.

The only advantage can be if your CustomRoleProvider will have some extra method, that you want to call, then you need to cast it.

Instantiation in that case would be:

```
var roles = new SimpleRoleProvider();
```

But in case of RoleProvider mechanisms it makes no sense, as it won't use Role providers collection

Comment: ok thank you. now you say it that makes sense. still learning.thanks

Answer (score 0):

When calling the method CreateRole there is no difference because it is available in both the Roles and SimpleRoleProvider classes.  The difference in these two classes is in the methods and properties available. Compare the [Roles class definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to 
the [definition of SimpleRoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simpleroleprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).  For example, Roles does not have a property UserIdColumn whereas SimpleRoleProvider does, because it is specific to the SimpleMebmership implementation and can be useful. Since SimpleRoleProvider is the actual provider configured for SimpleMembership it is safer to cast it to that provider. If you call a method in Roles that is not implemented in SimpleRoleProvider it will throw a not implemented exception. By casting to SimpleRoleProvider you can see what properties and methods are actually available to the provider with IntelaSense.